# emacs ess : how to auto complete library function

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am trying to migrate from RStudio to emacs ess
and i am trying now to find auto-completion functionality in emacs ess
similar to Rstudio

For my question i'll use a simple RStudio example
and i'll appreciate if you could tell me how to do the same in
emacs ess (The purpose is of course to generalize):

in `RStudio`

> when i type the text `libr` and then press TAB I get `library()`

inside the parentesis

> when i type "tidyv" like that: `library(tidyv)`
>   and then TAB i get `library(tidyverse)`

Could you please describe in a simple step by step manner how i can do the same in emacs ess?

Thanks

Rafael

Comment: This is a weak help because once my emacs does what I want I promptly forget how I made it work :). I have added: 

(require 'auto-complete-config)
(require 'auto-complete)
(ac-config-default)
(setq ess-tab-complete-in-script t)

To my '.emacs' ofcourse you need to install these first before it will work.

Comment: i think there is a pull request pending for exactly this feature: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/pull/502 for general autocompletion see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075012/emacs-ess-auto-complete?rq=1

Comment: Thanks trosendal. adding those statements to my .emacs file indeed provides auto completions for function names and arguments. However in the case of the library function no auto completions are provided for packages names. Any ideas?

Comment: according to the recent docs, ess prefers company mode.  However, I am unable to get that working at all.  Would really appreciate any info if you figure it out.  I am running Windows 10 64-bit, R 3.4.3 64-bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you with the default company-backend after a recent [backend addition](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/pull/509). You will just need to update your ESS from melpa. If `company-R-library` is not part of your `company-backends` in an ESS buffer, just add it in your ESS mode hook. Note that you should have set `ess-use-company`.

In response to comment, `ess-use-company` is a variable you should set to `t` in your config, not a function to call with <kbd>M-x</kbd>. I'll assume you have an init file, if not you can easily find information about that. Wherever you keep your config for ess in your init file, you could add (although this is the default, so unless you set `ess-use-auto-complete`, this is probably already set)

```
(setq ess-use-company t)
```

Every mode has a hook, which is a function it runs after it is setup in a buffer, allowing users to customize the mode. You can add such a hook using `(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'my-ess-mode-hook)`, where `my-ess-mode-hook` is a function you write with your customizations, eg. `(company-mode)` unless you have that turned on globally (most likely).

`company-backends` is also a variable, from an ESS buffer you can type <kbd>M-:</kbd>`company-backends` to evaluate lisp code to see the value of that variable. Make sure you reinstall the latest version of ESS from melpa.

Edit: full init to test -- `company-R-library` may not have been added to default backends

```
(setq-default package-archives 
              '(("melpa"        . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/")
                ("gnu"          . "http://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")))
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(package-initialize)

;;; company
(require 'company)
(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)

(setq company-idle-delay 0.5
      company-show-numbers t
      company-minimum-prefix-length 2
      company-tooltip-flip-when-above t)

(global-set-key (kbd "C-M-/") #'company-complete)
(global-company-mode)

;;; ESS
(defun my-ess-hook ()
  ;; ensure company-R-library is in ESS backends
  (make-local-variable 'company-backends)
  (cl-delete-if (lambda (x) (and (eq (car-safe x) 'company-R-args))) company-backends)
  (push (list 'company-R-args 'company-R-objects 'company-R-library :separate)
        company-backends))

(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'my-ess-hook)

(with-eval-after-load 'ess
  (setq ess-use-company t))
```

Start emacs with

```
emacs -Q -l /path/to/this/init.el
```

Open an R file, start the inferior R process, then type `library(ti` <kbd>M-C-/</kbd> and you should get package completions.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.  I installed the latest ess and company package from melpa. when i type ALT-X ess-use-c i can't find uss-use-company in my autocompletions .  the same is for company-R-library. Since i'm a very new emacs user it is quite possible i didn't understand the part of your answer dealing with adding it to my ess hook. I'll appreciate it if you could provide how to do it in a step by step manner. Thanks

Comment: Hi @jenesaisquoi .  i have added (setq ess-use-company t) to my emacs and restarted emacs. and added company mode by pressing M-x company-mode and still when i type library(   library(package= and then TAB no auto completions for libraries are provided. my ess version is 17.11 any ideas?

Comment: did you start an ess inferior R process? completions come from the running R process

Comment: Hi @jenesaisquoi . Yes. After opening a buffer called test.r i pressed the R icon on the toolbar and then sent an ls() command and got a response. and then when i type in the buffer library(  or library(package= and then TAB and  no auto completions for libraries are provided. What is company-R-library that you mentioned in your original response and how can i verify it's existence?

Comment: I wrote how already, evaluate the value of company-backend so in your ess buffer. It won’t complete there, but after “ti” it should complete for tidyr, etc. it might be worth going back and modifying the backend to complete all packages without a prefix, but it seems overkill to me

Comment: What is tab bound to? Probably not company-complete, which I bind to M-/ for example. You should call m-x company-complete to test instead of tab

Comment: @RafaelZanzoori the backend may not have been added to the default backends, you can use the above init file to test it out

Comment: Hi @jenesaisquoi. I saved init.el with the contents above in c:\Emacs and type emacs -Q -l c:/Emacs/init.el but when emacs loads i get a message command-line-1: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, c:/Emacs/init.el so i have replaced the contents of my .emacs file with the contents of init.el and restarted emacs but now i get the following messages: 
Company backend ’company-R-library’ could not be initialized:
Symbol’s function definition is void: company-R-library. I appreciate your patience

Comment: you should figure out how to use `emacs -Q -l` on windows as that way you start with a clean emacs and run the code. I don't use windows so I can;t help you there. That error sounds like you haven;t loaded a recent ESS

Comment: Hi @jenesaisquoi. It took me some time but i finally installed the latest version of emacs and ess and company package and it works. i think it didn't work the last time i tried because something in my .emacs file interfered with it. it works with an empty .emacs file. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi Hi, I've just upgraded to Debian10 and now Emacs version is 26.1, ess-version is 18.10.2 and company-mode is not in melpa-stable anymore. Looks like company-mode have been incorporated to Emacs. Any code/library completion working. Could you please possible give me some help? See .emacs in paste.debian.net/1096873

Comment: @fred I don't understand your question. Consider posting a new question, preferably with just the relevant part of your init

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I have it working for me, quite well with the following setup and steps:

- Windows 10 x64
- R 3.4.3 x64
- Emacs 25 x64 installed normally
- MELPA repo enabled in `init.el`
- `package-install [RET] company`
- `package-install [RET] ess`
- open a new R file in some directory
- `M-x company-mode` to enable `company-mode` in the current buffer
- `C-c C-z' to start an inferior R process (will not work without this)

At this point, autocomplete automatically pops up completion suggestions on R objects.  Autocomplete has to be triggered for inside parentheses.  Say I have my cursor inside the function parentheses for `shiny:runApp()`.  To get completion suggestions for the function arguments, I need to run the command `company-complete`.

You an do this with `M-x company-complete` or `M-x company-complete-common` and you should see the following:

[image]

I decided to bind this to Shift-Tab with the following line in my init.el:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<backtab>") 'company-complete-common)
```

And to have company mode enabled globally with:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)
```

Comment: Hi Vince.  Using that configuration can you auto-complete the following?  library(tidy + TAB .  The expected result should be  library(tidyverse).  for some reason i can't find a way to autocomplete packages names and data.frames field names like this : iris %>% select(Spe + TAB should yield iris %>% select(Species).  In RStudio it works without problems.  Thanks

Comment: No that doesn't work :-(.  I just tried it.  It autocompletes the function argument options for the library functions, and it will autocomplete functions and objects within the package name-space but it does not autocomplete the names of the package.  You might want to open an issue in the ESS github repo